# What CWinThread::PumpMessage does

Tags: c++, multithreading

While I debugging a windows application developed in C++, I found this function call `CWinThread::PumpMessage()`.
I have read in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1tkd768.aspx) and, a few other forum posts to understand. But still not sure what it does.

Can someone help me with the usability of this function?

Answer (score 4):

That's a handy function which prevents window from locking up. It's usage in MFC application is as follows:

```
void PumpWaitingMessages(){
   MSG msg; 
   while (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)){
      if (!AfxGetThread()->PumpMessage()) 
         return;
   }
}
```

For example, consider this function in a dialog box:

```
void CMyDialog::OnOK(){
       for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
          PumpWaitingMessages();
          Sleep(100);
          //do some lengthy calculations
       }
       MessageBox("done");
       CDialog::OnOK();
    }
```

If you call the above function the program should lock the thread for 5 seconds. But `PumpWaitingMessages();` will allow the program to respond keyboard and mouse input. But becareful because for example if you click the OK button twice in a row then the program will close the dialog box twice...

Comment: Which allows all sorts of *awesome* reentrancy issues to pop up. Also stuttering. And depending how long the other events take, it has no guarantee it will "lock the thread for 5 seconds".

Comment: This is not meant to lock the thread. Did you read my post? Why would anybody want to lock the thread in this way? There is nothing wrong with this method as long as it is not used as a substitute for multi-threading. It only stops the window from freezing.

Comment: Right, this is not meant to be in new code (should use multithreading in cases like this) but it's a life savor fixing issues in old code without making big changes like new threads.